# How to tell what languages phrases appear on the frontend?

Tags: language

I need to translate everything on my MSM sites into different languages. I notice that a lot of general error messages such as "The username you chose is not available" appear in the files in the folder `/system/expressionengine/language/xyz` however there are thousands of lines of phrases, most of which appear in the control panel only. How can I tell which phrases appear in the front end so I can translate them, without having to laboriously try to trigger each message or guess where they are used? I found language packs for German, French, Spanish but not Italian or Polish.

EE version 2.9.2

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look around and could not find language packs for either language, sorry (There is an Italian version but the price is high!).

I'm not aware of the 'minimum' list for front end translations either (lots on negative answer here I'm afraid). I do hope someone can give you a link to a positive answer though.

It might be down to you doing it yourself, using the [Translation Utility](http://voytrain2.gsu.edu/EEDocs/cp/admin/utilities/translation_utility.html)

Something that may help is that there are language packs for these for CodeIgnitor which EE is built on. It may well share a number of these phrases, even more so if its in the CI lang pack but not in the EE one, it's more likely to be an EE only/usind in CP/front end. [CI Language Packs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Translation)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's a shame there's no indication of where the phrases are used in the translation utility.